# SQL Server: Error converting data type varchar to numeric (Strange Behaviour)

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a legacy system using SQL Server in 2000 compatibility mode. There's a stored procedure that selects from a query into a virtual table.

When I run the query, I get the following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

which initially tells me that something stringy is trying to make its way into a numeric column.

To debug, I created the virtual table as a physical table and started eliminating each column.

The culprit column is called `accnum` (which stores a bank account number, which has a source data type of `varchar(21)`), which I'm trying to insert into a `numeric(16,0)` column, which obviously could cause issues.

So I made the `accnum` column `varchar(21)` as well in the physical table I created and it imports 100%. I also added an additional column called `accnum2` and made it `numeric(16,0)`.

After the data is imported, I proceeded to update `accnum2` to the value of `accnum`. Lo and behold, it updates without an error, yet it wouldn't work with an insert into...select query.

I have to work with the data types provided. Any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: Can you show us the query and table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to use conversion in your insert statement like this:

```
SELECT [accnum] = CASE ISNUMERIC(accnum) 
                     WHEN 0 THEN NULL 
                     ELSE CAST(accnum AS NUMERIC(16, 0)) 
                  END
```

Comment: That works. The weird thing is that the code I had before has remained unchanged for at least 4 years and this only occurred now. I extracted all the new bank account numbers and they look fine (did regex checks etc to check for spaces or non-numeric characters etc.) It's still a mystery why this occurred all of a sudden...

Comment: Be careful with that code. You might have come up with NULLs where a person might see a number. Something like "123456789-1" will produce NULL.